# wxPython FileOutputStream error

Tags: python, attributes, wxpython, runtime-error, fileoutputstream

I'm trying to learn wxPython/python and I want to save text in a file. I found this example

```
    def OnSaveAs(self, e):
    saveFileDialog = wx.FileDialog(self, "SAVE txt file", "", "", "Textdocument (*.txt)|*.txt", wx.FD_SAVE | wx.FD_OVERWRITE_PROMPT)
    if saveFileDialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
        return     # User canceled

    # save the current contents in the file
    # this can be done with e.g. wxPython output streams:
    output_stream = wx.FileOutputStream(saveFileDialog.GetPath())
    #My question: Insert what to write to output_stream here?
    if not out_stream.IsOk():
        wx.LogError("Cannot save current contents in file '%s'."%saveFileDialog.GetPath())
        return
```

I get the error

```
in OnSaveAs output_stream = wx.FileOutputStream(saveFileDialog.GetPath()) AttributeError 'module' object has no attribute 'FileOutputStream'
```

Shouldnt output_stream contain the path to the file i want to save. And then I write to output_stream to save text in the file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Just use the Python functions to open and write content to the file.  Something like this:

```
output = open(saveFileDialog.GetPath(), 'w')
ouput.write(stuff)
ouput.close()
```

In almost all cases wxPython only wraps the wxWidgets classes and functions which do not already have an equivallent in Python, and the `AttributeError` is telling you that there is no `wx.FileOutputStream` class available.